# How work with malloc and array of struct pointer

Tags: c

I would like to try allocating my first 10 structs. We have to store an array of struct pointer at the heap but I don't know what i am doing wrong

my struct looks like this

```c
typedef struct TEST
{
    char* first_string;
    char* second_string;
} test;
```

what i have written:

```c
test **string_pair;

string_pair = malloc(10 * sizeof(test *));
  if(string:pair == NULL)
  {
    free(string_pair);
    exit(4);
  }
```

This works fine
However later I am trying in an for loop to allocate my strings

```c
string_pair[count]->first_string = malloc(10 * sizeof(char)); // note that count is currently 0
  if(string_pair[count]->first_string == NULL)
  {
    free(string_pair[count]->first_string);
    free(string_pair[count]);
    exit(4);
  }
```

And I get an segmentation fault

Before anyone suggests we are not allowed to simply use an array of structs we have to do it the complicated way.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a segmentation fault because you are allocating an array of pointers but not allocating the structure itself.

With `string_pair = malloc(10 * sizeof(test *));`, you allocate `string_pair` (a pointer to a pointer) to 10 pointers (pointing to a `test` structure).

Then, with `string_pair[count]->first_string = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));`, you allocate the `first_string` member of `string_pair[count]` to a string of 10 characters. The `->` token means to access the member in `string_pair[count]`. However, the actual structure is not allocated.

You need to allocate `string_pair[count]`, with something like `string_pair[count] = malloc(sizeof(test));`.

I'd recommend just using a `test*` for your array, and allocating it with `test* string_pair = malloc(10 * sizeof(test));`.

Answer (score 1):

You allocated an array of pointers.

But you did not allocate memory for the actual structures, and you did not initialize the pointers you allocated.

This line:

```
string_pair = malloc(10 * sizeof(test *));
```

Allocates array of 4 or 8 (depending on your architecture) byte variables that can store memory addresses.

It does not allocate `struct TEST`.
The pointers will contain garbage (possibly invalid) addresses until you initialize them.

You are suppose to do it by calling `malloc` for `struct TEST`, and placing the resulting pointer in the array.

Otherwise, when your code reaches this line:

```
string_pair[count]->first_string
```

it will look for `struct TEST` at some random address, possibly 0, and try to read its `first_string` field, which will cause segmentation fault.